# Python Regular Expression to combine outer text with text between tags

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string (stage 1):

```
(Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah=">PHYS 218</A> Minimum Grade of D) and (Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">MATH 152</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="/blah=">MATH 172</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">MATH 251</A> Minimum Grade of D)
```

From this I go to (stage 2):

```
(Undergraduate level PHYS 218 Minimum Grade of D) and (Undergraduate level MATH 152 Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level MATH 172 Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level MATH 251 Minimum Grade of D)
```

And then ultimately what I want is (stage 3):

```
(PHYS 218) and (MATH 152 or MATH 172 or MATH 251)
```

Currently the way I am doing this is horrible.

I take the stage 1 string, remove all the `a` tags completely and combine the text that is left.

I then take the course numbers from the `a` tags and put it into the string from the above step to get to the second stage.

I then look for the course in the second stage, remove everything to the left and right of it till I hit a `(`, `)`, `or`, `and`.

Is there any way I can do this cleanly using regular expressions or maybe something else? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="""(Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah=">PHYS 218</A> Minimum Grade of D) and (Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">MATH 152</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="/blah=">MATH 172</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">MATH 251</A> Minimum Grade of D)"""
import re
print re.sub(r"<[^>]*>\s*|Undergraduate level\s*|Minimum Grade of [A-Z]+","",x)
```

You can do it with `re.sub` if the format is always fixed and will not change much.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hF7zZ1/2

EDIT:

If text is changing try this

```
x="""(Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah=">PHYS 218</A> Minimum Grade of D) and (Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">MATH 152</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="/blah=">MATH 172</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">MATH 251</A> Minimum Grade of D)"""
import re
print "".join(re.findall(r"(\(|\)|\s*or\s*|\s*and\s*|(?<=>)[^<]*(?=<\/A>))",x))
```

Comment: This works for the case given like you said, but the text outside of the tags can change as well as the and/or combinations. But thanks.

Comment: @Random102 can you post other type of string?

Comment: Here's two other I found: 
`(Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">CHEM 102</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">CHEM 104</A> Minimum Grade of D) and (Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">CHEM 112</A> Minimum Grade of D or Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">CHEM 114</A> Minimum Grade of D) and Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">CHEM 227</A> Minimum Grade of D`

and 

`Undergraduate level  <A HREF="blah">CHEM 117</A> Minimum Grade of D`